# Server infected with Backdoor:Win32/Caphaw.D virus

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, anti-virus, microsoft-forefront

The virsu hiding all of the folders and replace it with shortcut.

These are the setting in shortcuts.

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C start cmd.exe /C if exist "\\server\folder\hAoix.NCf" start "" "\\server\folder\hAoix.NCf" && start "" "\\server\folder\cs3can"

C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C start cmd.exe /C if exist "\\server\folder\hAoix.NCf" start "" "\\server\folder\hAoix.NCf" && start "" "\\server\Unloads\cs3d3t"

C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C start cmd.exe /C if exist "\\server\folder\hAoix.NCf" start "" "\\server\folder\hAoix.NCf" && start "" "\\server\Unloads\cs3mex\unload_from_vegas_20120501"
```

I just complated full scan on server and it found this

Backdoor:Win32/Caphaw.D
 .

Category:

Backdoor

Description:

This program provides remote access to the computer it is installed on.

Recommended action: 
Remove this software immediately.

Forefront Endpoint Protection detected programs that may compromise your privacy or damage your computer. You can still access the files that these programs use without removing them (not recommended). To access these files, select the Allow action and click Apply actions. If this option is not available, log on as administrator or ask the security administrator for help.

Items:

file:E:\applications\Insite\Documents\Maps\xuAaQgW.hSp

Get more information about this item online.

Update:
Why this was not been picked up by the Microsoft Forefront?

I like to create a script which goes through these server and delete and shortcut which has `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C start cmd.exe /C` .

If I try to go throguht manually it will take long time.

I have used this command in side a folder. `del /s *.lnk` which does the job but it deletes anything which is lnk

I only like to delete shortcut which begains with `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /C start cmd.exe /C`.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Please check my update

Comment: I asked new question here. http://serverfault.com/questions/504488/server-infected-with-backdoorwin32-caphaw-d-virus-need-script-to-clear-shortcu

Answer (score 0):

cleanup.bat

```
@echo off
set delims="delims=;"
for /F %%a in ('findstr /m /i /r "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe[ ][ ]*/Cstart[ ][ ]*cmd.exe[ ][ ]*/C" c:\directory\*.lnk') do (
@echo %%a
echo rem del %%a
)
```

Comment: I try to run this script in a folder but it doesn't delete any of the files. Also I need to include and sub folders

Comment: I ask new question here. http://serverfault.com/questions/504488/server-infected-with-backdoorwin32-caphaw-d-virus-need-script-to-clear-shortcu